# Center ad received with width larger then screen using PublisherAdView

Tags: java, android

I've got a PublisherAdView within a RelativeLayout. I'm getting an ad with width of 410dp which is larger then device width. I'm trying to center the ad so it will get cut a little from both sides but it's been aligned to the left edge of the screen and the right side is getting cut.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!-- Ads view -->
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView
        android:id="@+id/urlBannerAdView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
```